# Proving that $E=F\oplus G$ for two given subspaces of $E = \mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose that $F ={(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 |x−y+z=0}$ and $g=(1,1,1)$ with $G=Vect(g)$

How can I prove that $E=F\oplus G$?

I'm wondering how many ways exist to prove that?

Answer (score 3):

$F$ has dimension $2$ because it's the $0$-set of a linear form and $G$ has dimension $1$ Since $g$ does not satisfy the equation $x-y+z=0$, $g\notin F$ so that $F\cap G=\{0\}$ and the sum $F+G$ is direct.

Finally $\Bbb R^3=F\oplus G$ because $E=\Bbb R^3$ and $F\oplus G$ have both dimension $3$.